# Square-free numbers congruent to $1$ modulo $p$ (asymptotic formula)

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, characters

> Knowing that $\sum_{n\leq x}\mu^2(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2}x+O(\sqrt{x})$, prove that:
>
> $$\sum_{n\leq x,\,\,n\equiv 1(\text{mod }p)}\mu^2(n)=\frac{6}{\pi^2(p-1)}x+O(\sqrt{x})$$

Using Dirichlet charaters, we have:
\begin{align*}
\sum_{n\leq x,\,\,n\equiv 1(\text{mod }p)}\mu^2(n)&=\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{n\leq x}\sum_{\chi(\text{mod }p)}\mu^2(n)\chi(n)\\
&=\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{\chi(\text{mod }p)}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu^2(n)\chi(n)\\
&=\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu^2(n)\chi_0(n)+\underbrace{\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{\chi\neq \chi_0}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu^2(n)\chi(n)}_{=:\Delta(x)}
\end{align*}
Where $\chi_0$ is the principal character. I was able to prove that $\Delta(x)=O(\sqrt{x})$ basically by using the fact that $\mu^2(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)$, and that $\left|\sum_{n\leq x}\chi(n)\right|\leq \varphi(p)$. My problem is the main term, which doesn't match my calculation.

By definition, $\chi_0(n)=1$ if $p\not| n$ and $\chi_0(n)=0$ if $p|n$. Therefore:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu^2(n)\chi_0(n)&=\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu^2(n)-\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{n\leq x,\,\,p|n}\mu^2(n)\\
&=\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{n\leq x}\mu^2(n)-\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\sum_{n\leq \frac{x}{p}}\mu^2(n)\\
&=\frac{1}{\varphi(p)}\left(\frac{6}{\pi^2}x-\frac{6}{\pi^2}\frac{x}{p}\right)+O(\sqrt{x})\\
&=\frac{6x}{\pi^2\varphi(p)}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)+O(\sqrt{x})\\
&=\frac{6}{\pi^2p}x+O(\sqrt{x})
\end{align*}
What am I missing?

Comment: $\sum_{n \le x} \mu^2(n) 1_{(n,p)=1}= Res(\frac{(1-p^{-s})\zeta(s)}{s(1-p^{-2s})\zeta(2s)}x^s,1) +O(x^{1/2})= \frac{1}{(1+p^{-1})\zeta(2)}x+O(x^{1/2})$ so that $\sum_{n \le x} \mu^2(n) 1_{n \equiv 1 \bmod p} = \frac{6}{\pi^2 (p-1)(1+p^{-1})}x+O(x^{1/2})$

Comment: Sorry @reuns I'm still not familiarized with the complex analytic approach for this kind of sum. How did you get to $\text{Res}\left(\frac{(1-p^{-s})\zeta(s)}{s(1-p^{-2p})\zeta(2s)}x^s,1\right)$? Is there any reference you would particularly recommend to that technique? Thank you!

Comment: At first it is just saying that $\sum_{n \le x} a_n = C x+O(x^{1-\epsilon}) \implies$ (the analytic continuation of) $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n n^{-s}- \frac{C}{s-1}$ is analytic for $\Re(s) > 1-\epsilon$. Replacing $\implies$ by $\Leftrightarrow$ (under some conditions on $a_n$) is the purpose of tauberian theorems appearing in the proof of the PNT and any text on analytic number theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your treatment of the main term you have missed that
$$\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ p \mid n}} \mu^2(n)$$
is not quite the same as
$$\sum_{n \leqslant x/p} \mu^2(n) = Q\biggl(\frac{x}{p}\biggr)\,.$$
For large enough $x$, there are squarefree $n \leqslant x/p$ that are themselves divisible by $p$ and therefore do *not* give rise to a squarefree $m \leqslant x$ that is divisible by $p$. We have
$$\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ p \mid n}} \mu^2(n) = \sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x/p \\ p \nmid n}} \mu^2(n)\,.$$
And we're back at the beginning, just with an upper limit of $x/p$ instead of $x$. Iterating the argument yields
$$\sum_{\substack{n \leqslant x \\ p \mid n}} \mu^2(n) = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^k Q\biggl(\frac{x}{p^k}\biggr) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}x\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^k}{p^k} + O(\sqrt{x}) = \frac{6}{\pi^2\bigl(1 + \frac{1}{p}\bigr)} x + O(\sqrt{x})$$
and hence
$$\sum_{n \equiv 1 \pmod{p}} \mu^2(n) = \frac{6p}{\pi^2(p^2-1)}x + O(\sqrt{x})\,.$$
Thus the formula you were asked to prove is indeed wrong, but by a smaller factor (namely $\frac{p+1}{p}$) than you thought (namely $\frac{p}{p-1}$).